# How to remove react prop type warning in react console

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using development mode and I need my console to be clear enough. How can I remove react prop type warning in components? I'm using react-native-web in my stack and possibly it causes these warnings.

Answer (score 2):

> console.disableYellowBox = true;

This will solve the problem.

For more details https://codedaily.io/tutorials/5/Disable-the-Yellow-Box-in-React-Native

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to import prop types like this.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install `npm i prop-types --save`

Then use `import PropTypes from 'prop-types`;

Then `<ComponentName>.propTypes={
  Prop1: PropTypes.* 
  Prop2: PropTypes.* 
 }`

Where * =

> array , bool, func, number, object, string, symbol

Answer (score 0):

Share more info on the exact prop-type that is causing the warning. My guess is that you are passing the wrong prop-type, say you are passing a `string` to a `number`. Correct that and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easy tool to convert old code React style using react-codemod and jscodeshift, first download it from here

install jscodeshift

```
npm install -g jscodeshift
```

Download

https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod

and put it in your application node_modules

then use the following command convert the prop types in any path, this should work on a folder of your component

```
jscodeshift -t {PATH_YOUR_MAIN_APP}/node_modules/react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js {PATH_FOR_COMPONENT_YOU_WANT_TO_CONVERT}
```

For advance and major changes you can use other options like the following

```
jscodeshift -t {PATH_YOUR_MAIN_APP}/node_modules/react-codemod/transforms/class.js --mixin-module-name=react-addons-pure-render-mixin --flow=true --pure-component=true --remove-runtime-proptypes=false {PATH_FOR_COMPONENT_YOU_WANT_TO_CONVERT}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution was to go onto your web browsers console and right click the react console warning and you should see something such as `hide messages from 0.chunk.js`, press that and you should no longer get that spam.

To get the messges back just clear the filter at the top of the console window.

Answer (score -3):

**`import PropTypes from "prop-types";`**

```
class Profile extends Component {
...

static propTypes = {
    networkInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    list: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    id : PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };
```

### Warning can be remove

Data types can be handle:   `array , bool, func, number, object, string, symbol, any`

Reference : [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

#### INSTALL [PropType](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

`npm i prop-types --save`